# Change XMPP registered user password using asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am creating an android app which also has an integrated XMPP chat feature using aSmack and ejabberd. I am using the user's application login and password to login to XMPP server. 
So how do I change a password using aSmack in case a user changes his application password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it unless you create a plugin for it.

The alternate is to delete the user and create him again.

one more alternate can be just married plugin https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/justmarried/readme.html 
this plugin change the username. You can modify the plugin to change pssword. Note : just married plugin is also deleting the user and recreating it but restoring all the data

Comment: But deleting and creation shall also delete all of his joined rooms and stuff

Comment: But can it be used for ejabberd as well??

Comment: I am not sure. Never used ejabberd. One up for last answer

Answer (score 2):

First of all, according to [Smack API documentation](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) "Starting with 4.1, Smack is able to run natively and unmodified on Android."

There you can use [AccountManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html) class method `getInstance(XMPPConnection connection)` to get an instance. The object has a method `changePassword(String newPassword)` that you can use to change the account password.

There are other useful methods such as `createAccount(...)`, etc ...

Make sure that the above works with the XMPP server that you use.

Please note that in general not all features described in the XMMP specification are available on all XMPP server implementations. You should always check with your server documentation.

REF: [Smack API JavaDoc](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/)